# How to find the parent element that loads the children elements without explicitly declaring it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, load, parent-child

How can I find the parent element that loads the children elements without explicitly declaring it from **another** function?

the jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.load-child').load_child();

    });


    (function($) {

        $.fn.extend({ 

            load_child: function(options) {

                var o = $.extend({
                    target:'.parent'
                }, options);

                var $this = this;

                var $cm = this.click(function(e) {

                    var object = $(this);
                    var path = object.attr('href');

                    $(o.target).load(path, function(){

                        $this.child();

                    });

                    return false;

                });


                $this.child = function() {

                    $('.find-parent').click(function(event){

                        var object = $(this);
                        object.parents('.parent').css({background:'red'});

                        return false;
                    })

                };


                return $cm;

            }
        })
    })(jQuery);
```

index html,

```
<a href="child.php" class="load-child">load child</a>

<div class="container">

    <div class="parent">    

    </div>

</div>
```

child page,

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="find-parent">click me</a></div>
</div>
```

I can get the `.parent` element above because I declare the parent name explicitly,

```
object.parents('.parent').css({background:'red'});
```

But what about if the parent name is unknown or is changed constantly? Is there any generic method to locate/ trace back to the element that is used to load the page?

The loaded page may have loads of div elements, so I can't do this,

```
object.parent().css({background:'red'});
```

or

```
object.parents(div).css({background:'red'}); // this will go up to the very top of div element.
```

the [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/G5prz/).

**Edit:**

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ycHJc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are your options:

1. You mark the parent in some way (easiest is probably with a special class name) when you load the content.  Then the content can search up the ancestor chain with `.closest(".markerName")` to find it from anywhere within the content.
2. You know something about the structure of the loaded content so that the content knows where it's top is and can go one above that to find the load parent.
3. You store the load parent in a globally reachable javascript variable so the content can fetch that when it needs it.

Note, I think you generally want to be used `.closest(selector)` instead of `.parents(selector)`.  You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

**Edit** - based on the question you ask in your comment:

Storing the load parent in a global variable is my least recommended option, but since you ask how to do it this is how:

When your load-child method does this:

```
$(o.target).load(path, function(){
```

you would just remember the `o.target` value like this:

```
window.loadTarget = $(o.target);
```

Then, `window.loadTarget` will be a global variable containing where you last loaded content.

Personally, I would much prefer you use a special class name.  So, you'd replace this:

```
$(o.target).load(path, function(){
```

with this:

```
$(o.target).addClass("loadTarget").load(path, function(){
```

and then, anywhere inside the content that you want to find the load target, you'd do this:

```
$(this).closest("loadTarget")
```

This second option avoids any new global variables and supports multiple loadTargets at the same time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. how do I store the load parent in a globally variable?

Comment: @lauthiamkok - I add more info to the end of my answer.

Comment: I can see that global variables are evil like in PHP, is there any way to destroy the global variable after using it?

Comment: found the way to destroy it - `loadTarget = undefined;` :-)

Comment: I just thought a solution which is using `data()` - have a look in my edit :-)

Comment: That is fine as long as you can find the load-child object again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `closest()` instead.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a generic class?

Comment: too many generic classes in use already so I thought there could be other better solutions...